# Is this function, to determine the result of rock paper scissors, correct?

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that tells you the result of a rock paper scissors game given two inputs:

```
data Move = Paper | Rock | Scissors
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Result =  Win | Draw | Lose   
    deriving (Eq, Show)

-- function returns the move which beats the other move
beats :: Move -> Move
beats move = case move of
    Paper    -> Scissors
    Rock     -> Paper
    Scissors -> Rock

loses :: Move -> Move
loses move = case move of
    Scissors -> Paper
    Paper -> Rock
    Rock -> Scissors

-- find out what the score is for moves and return Win or Draw or Lose
score :: Move -> Move -> Result
score this_move opposing_move = case this_move of
    opposing_move -> Draw
    beats opposing_move -> Win
    loses opposing_move -> Lose
```

It returns the error message:

```
parse error on input ‘=’
```

This means there is a problem with one of the equals signs i wrote in the code right? I don't see any problems with an of the equals signs though.

Comment: your identation over the `case` look bad for me, they should be pass che `c` from case

Comment: it's in the case of `loses` - you are using `=` instead of `->`  - just compare to the other ones - I could not find the usual tab problems - the `score` function might cause some problems too - better use guards

Comment: btw: you don't need the `case` at all if you just use pattern matching: `loses Scissor = Paper` etc.

Comment: the logic itself seems fine and it's even in good/readable style - just correct the one syntax problem and you should be good to go

Comment: You can't `case this_move of other_move -> ...` and expect that to check for equality. That will instead re-bind the `other_move` variable to the value of `this_move`. Enabling warnings with `-Wall` will spot this error ("overlapping patterns").

Comment: @ Carsten I made the changes, and it now says "parse error in patterns: beats" I have never seen this error before.

Comment: @chi, Sorry, what do you mean by re-bind? and if that is not the way to compare the two variables, how would i compare them instead?

Comment: @dominiontowa maybe you should update your question ...

Comment: @dominiontowa Basically you're defining a new local variable which is called `opposing_move` which has nothing to do with the parameter of the same name. It's similar to `let x=5 in (let x=7 in 3+x)`, where the outer `x` is shadowed. For a proper comparison, you have to use `==`, e.g. with guards. See e.g. the chepner answer below, which includes the guarded line `score x y | x==y = Draw`. You can also avoid using `==` if you list all the three cases explicitly `score Paper Paper = Draw ; score Rock Rock = Draw ; ...`

Answer (score 4):

As Carsten pointed out, this is far simpler with pattern matching; you don't even need intermediate functions.

```
score :: Move -> Move -> Result
score Paper Rock = Win  -- paper beats rock
score Rock Scissors = Win -- rock beats scissors
score Scissors Paper = Win -- scissors beats paper
score x y | x == y = Draw  -- same move is a draw
score _ _ = Lose -- anything else is a loss
```

Answer (score 2):

and here is a version very close to yours

```
-- function returns the move which beats the other move
beats :: Move -> Move -> Bool
beats Scissors Paper = True
beats Paper Rock     = True
beats Rock Scissors  = True
beats _ _            = False

loses_to :: Move -> Move -> Bool
loses_to = flip beats

-- find out what the score is for moves and return Win or Draw or Lose
score :: Move -> Move -> Result
score this_move opposing_move
  | this_move `beats` opposing_move    = Win
  | this_move `loses_to` opposing_move = Lose
  | otherwise                          = Draw
```

Comment: Did you mean to write "|  beats this_move opposing_move    = Win" instead? beat is a function so should take parameters at the end right?

Comment: if you use backticks ``a `f` b`` -  it's the same as `f a b` - but it reads nicer - that's why I reversed the cases here too - you need the functions to return a `Bool` to work as guards too

Comment: `loses_to = flip beats`

Comment: @amalloy good point - indeed I forgot the last case of `loses_to` anyway ... ;)